# Calling Multiple Object/Variables "Name" with Looping

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008

I got stucked on making looping for adding these Variables to ComboBox, i want to call it with a simpler way with Looping for, but i failed so many times, i've been googling around but i still failed, so any help will be appreciated

```
Public MyPass1 As String = "John"
Public MyPass2 As String = "Andrew"
Public MyPass3 As String = "Stewart"
Public MyPass4 As String = "Meiny"
Public MyPass5 As String = "Franco"
Public MyPass6 As String = "Hanks"
Public MyPass7 As String = "Buzz"
Public MyPass8 As String = "Timmy"
Public MyPass9 As String = "George"
Public MyPass10 As String = "Sanders"

Sub Putitem(ByVal MyPass)
    With cmbAsk
        For i As Integer = 0 To 9
            Dim c As Integer
            c = i + 1
            Items.Add(MyPass(c)) 'The main problem is here, i want to do looping for calling it.
            i = c
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of storing the values in individual variables, you can store them in an array:

```
Public MyPasses As String() = New String() { 
                             "John",
                             "Andrew",  
                             "Stewart",
                             "Meiny",
                             "Franco",
                             "Hanks",
                             "Buzz",
                             "Timmy",
                             "George",                               
                             "Sanders"
                          }
```

You can then access via:

```
Items.Add(MyPasses(c))
```

Comment: Yes, you're right, That's the best choice by using array, but eerrr i'm just curious about calling multiple variables with looping for. so, any clue will be appreciated.

Comment: @laruffii The only way to accomplish this with separate variables would be to use Reflection, which is slow and error prone.  See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163750.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You need a collection to add not public strings.

```
Private collection() As String = {"John", "Mark", "Frank"} 'initializer

cmbAsk.Items.AddRange(collection.ToArray)
```

[AddRange method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.objectcollection.addrange.aspx)